Issues with deleting files from System 32 using a PowerShell script
this is the script I'm working with
# Define the top-level folder and the list of files
$topFolder = "C:\Windows\System32"  # Update to System32 directory
$files = @(
     "mstsc.exe",
    "mstscax.dll",
    "msra.exe",
    "termsrv.dll",
    "termmgr.dll",
    "rdpclip.exe",
    "tscon.exe",
    "tsdiscon.exe",
    "qwinsta.exe",
    "shadow.exe",
    "sessenv.dll",
    "sessmgr.exe",
    "rdpshell.exe",
    "rdpint.exe",
    "rdpcorekmts.dll",
    "rdpcore.dll",
    "rdpdd.dll",
    "rdpsnd.dll",
    "termsrv.exe",
    "rdpendp.dll",
    "rdprefmp.dll",
    "rdpendin.dll",
    "rasadhlp.dll",
    "rasman.dll",
    "rasapi32.dll",
    "rdpencom.dll",
    "rdpendcom.dll",
    "rdpcredentialprovider.dll",
    "rdpsa.exe",
    "rasppp.dll",
    "rdpsaps.dll",
    "rdpsauachelper.exe",
    "rdpsharecom.dll",
    "rdpudd.dll",
    "rdpviewerax.dll",
    "rascustom.dll",
    "rasctrnm.h",
    "rasctrs.dll",
    "rasgcw.dll",
    "rasmbmgr.dll",
    "rasmm.dll",
    "rasmontr.dll",
    "rasphone.exe",
    "rasplap.dll",
    "rastlsext.dll",
    "msrdc.dll",
    "msrdpwebaccess.dll",
    "sessionmsg.exe",
    "rasautou.exe",
    "raschap.dll",
    "raschapext.dll",
    "rasdiag.dll",
    "rasdial.dll",
    "rasdig.dll",
    "raserver.exe",
    "rasmans.dll",
    "rasmediamanager.dll",
    "rasmm.dll",
    "rasstapi.dll",
    "rastls.dll",
    "rdpbase.dll",
    "rdpcfgex.dll",
    "rdpcorets.dll",
    "rdpviewerax.dll",
    "rdpinput.exe",
    "rdpnano.dll",
    "RdpRelayTransport.dll",
    "RdpSaProxy.exe",
    "rdpserverbase.dll",
    "rdpsign.exe",
    "RDSAppXHelper.dll",
    "rdsdwmdr.dll",
    "rdvvmtransport.dll"   
)

# Function to move files to the Recycle Bin
function Move-ToRecycleBin {
    param (
        [string]$filePath
    )
    $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $folder = $shell.Namespace((Get-Item $filePath).DirectoryName)
    $item = $folder.ParseName((Get-Item $filePath).Name)
    $item.InvokeVerb('delete')  # Move to Recycle Bin
}

try {
    # Take ownership of the top-level folder recursively
    Write-Output "Taking ownership of $topFolder and all child objects..."
    takeown /F $topFolder /R /D Y | Out-Null
    Write-Output "Ownership taken for $topFolder and all child objects."

    # Grant full control permissions to the Administrators group recursively
    Write-Output "Granting full control permissions to Administrators for $topFolder and all child objects..."
    icacls $topFolder /grant Administrators:F /T /C /Q | Out-Null
    Write-Output "Full control granted to Administrators for $topFolder and all child objects."

    # Wait a few seconds to ensure permissions are applied
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

    # Loop through each file in the list and delete it
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $filePath = Join-Path -Path $topFolder -ChildPath $file
        Write-Output "Checking $filePath..."
        if (Test-Path -Path $filePath) {
            Write-Output "$filePath exists. Attempting to move to Recycle Bin..."
            try {
                # Output file attributes and permissions before moving
                $fileInfo = Get-Item -Path $filePath
                Write-Output "File: $filePath"
                Write-Output "Attributes: $($fileInfo.Attributes)"
                Write-Output "Permissions: $(Get-Acl -Path $filePath | Format-List | Out-String)"

                # Move to Recycle Bin
                Move-ToRecycleBin -filePath $filePath
                Write-Output "Moved $filePath to Recycle Bin"
            } catch {
                # Output the exception message using concatenation
                $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                Write-Output ("Error moving " + $filePath + ": " + $errorMessage)
            }
        } else {
            Write-Output "$filePath does not exist"
        }
    }

} catch {
    Write-Output ("Error processing: {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
}

When I run it everything works with no errors
C:\Windows\System32\rdvvmtransport.dll exists. Attempting to move to Recycle Bin...
File: C:\Windows\System32\rdvvmtransport.dll
Attributes: Archive
Permissions:

Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows\System32\rdvvmtransport.dll
Owner  : DESKTOP-USHGRVA\garrett
Group  : NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller
Access : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
         NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller Allow  FullControl
         APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
         APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-21-3924358604-886122918-2420348639-1001G:S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-227147846
         4D:PAI(A;;0x1200a9;;;SY)(A;;FA;;;BA)(A;;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-185329
         2631-2271478464)(A;;0x1200a9;;;AC)(A;;0x1200a9;;;S-1-15-2-2)    

But after I check the system32 folder, nothing has changed. What's worse is the recycle bin populates with the listed files.  I can empty the recycle bin and everything, but when I browse back to system 32 I find all the files listed with permissions set to TrustedInstaller and Administrator account at Read & Execute . I've checked group policy and Windows Defender but both are not the issue since Defender is turned off and Group Policy is set to allow all scripts.
Is there a better way to do this?
If any one has any ideas what is going wrong or why its only half-way working I'm all ears.

Windows is likely restoring the files. Why are you deleting required system files?

These files pertain to windows remote desktop, terminal services, and remote assistance. Since windows 10 has no dedicated un-installer for these programs (only available on WIN 11) I decided to make my own. when i tested it I made sure to check task scheduler and delete any entries for remote desktop and remote and if I go threw and delete manually they stay gone. I run it and it populates the recycle bin with the listed files and everything. I reboot and run it again it says all files are not there. But I'm getting read outs that directly contradict what I'm seeing in windows explorer.

Why bother? Just disable all RDP services. Even if you do remove 'em, at the next update Windows would likely reinstall 'em.
